# How can I get GCC 4.7 installed on Precise?

Tags: 12.04, gcc, versions, backport

The [latest version of GCC in the Precise archives](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gcc) is 4.6.3. However, GCC 4.7 adds support for some newer C++11 features (like delegating constructors). Quantal's package archives have GCC 4.7.2 available.

Is there any way I can get GCC 4.7 installed on Precise? Better yet, is there an easy way to take a newer version of a package in one release and backport it to an older release?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have created a PPA that contains a build of GCC 4.7 for Precise here:

[ppa:george-edison55/gcc4.7-precise [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/gcc4.7-precise) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

---

To backport a package from one release to another is a relatively simple process assuming you have a Launchpad account and have registered your GPG key there.

Make sure you have the [ubuntu-dev-tools [image: Install ubuntu-dev-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-dev-tools) package installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools
```

The syntax for running the backport command looks something like this:

```
backportpackage -s [new_release] -d [old_release] -u [ppa] [package_name]
```

The command above will backport `[package_name]` from `[new_release]` to `[old_release]`and upload it to `[ppa]`. Note that in this particular case you will need to backport not only `gcc-4.7` but also `gcj-4.7` and `gcc-defaults` *in that order*.

Comment: hard to believe it's that easy \0/

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more easy way is to just utilize the [Ubuntu Toolchain Uploaders (Restricted) Team's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test?field.series_filter=precise) of test builds, which has Toolchain builds (this includes gcc, etc.) of newer toolchains in older releases.  The above link shows the Precise packages there but they do compile things.

The releases available include gcc 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, and 5, although I've only tested 4.7.

You can always backport your own gcc packages and such, but that can always take time.